# Power Query - Group based on two filters

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm working on a simplification of some of my reports by using Power Query.
I have a table with this structure:
[image]

In the first column we can see the Sales Order Number.
In the second column we can see the Message type. If it is a XR or PR Message.
And in the last column we can find the Key for the status:

- A = Active
- B = Active
- C = Closed

With this logic I would like to get this result table:

[image]

This way I can see as a cross table the type and the state per sales order.
How is this possible by using Power Query?

Comment: It looks like your last row has XR and PR mixed up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure about your results for Sales Order 103?

Try the following M code, amending where necessary (`Source` step, for example):

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content], 
  XRCol = Table.AddColumn(
    Source, 
    "XR", 
    each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Message], "-") = "XR", 
    type logical
  ), 
  PRCol = Table.AddColumn(
    XRCol, 
    "PR", 
    each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Message], "-") = "PR", 
    type logical
  ), 
  XRActCol = Table.AddColumn(PRCol, "XR Active", each [XR] and [Key] <> "C", type logical), 
  PRActCol = Table.AddColumn(XRActCol, "PR Active", each [PR] and [Key] <> "C", type logical), 
  RemoveCols = Table.RemoveColumns(PRActCol, {"Message", "Key"}), 
  Group = Table.Group(
    RemoveCols, 
    {"Sales Order"}, 
    {
      {"XR", each List.Max([XR]), type logical}, 
      {"PR", each List.Max([PR]), type logical}, 
      {"XR Active", each List.Max([XR Active]), type logical}, 
      {"PR Active", each List.Max([PR Active]), type logical}
    }
  )
in
  Group
```

Comment: You are right, Order 103 is not right. PR should be active

Answer (score 1):

If I see it correctly your output PR and XR is mixed up in Sales order 103.

Try if this works for you:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\maitting\Documents\Mappe1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Tabelle1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Tabelle1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Tabelle1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Sales Order", Int64.Type}, {"Message", type text}, {"Key", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Message", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Message"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Message", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1","A","Active",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Key"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","B","Active",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Key"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","C","Closed",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Key"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Replaced Value2",{"Message", "Key"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" - ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Merged Columns", {"Sales Order"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Value]), "Value", "Attribute", List.Count),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "XR", 
        each if [#"XR - Active"] = 1 then 1 
        else if [#"XR - Closed"] = 1 then 1 
        else 0),
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "PR", 
        each if [#"PR - Active"] = 1 then 1 
        else if [#"PR - Closed"] = 1 then 1 
        else 0),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Conditional Column1",{"XR - Closed", "PR - Closed"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Sales Order", "XR", "PR", "XR - Active", "PR - Active"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"XR", type logical}, {"PR", type logical}, {"XR - Active", type logical}, {"PR - Active", type logical}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

**Output:**

[image]

I've just added Sales order 104 with PR Closed to handle all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

My version

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
RemoveEndingColumn = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Message", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "-"), type text}}),
#"Create MessageKey" = Table.AddColumn(RemoveEndingColumn, "MessageKey", each [Message]&" "&[Key]),
StackColumns = Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Create MessageKey",{"Sales Order", "Message"}),{{"Message", "Column"}})& Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Create MessageKey",{"Sales Order", "MessageKey"}),{{"MessageKey", "Column"}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(StackColumns, "TrueFalse", each true, type logical),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom1", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom1"[Column]), "Column", "TrueFalse")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]